# SSL Certificate for Azure Cloud Services

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate

I intend to host a WCF Service with a HTTPS endpoint in Azure Cloud Services.
Assuming that I have a SSL certificate for 'mydomain.net', and azure demands an address like 'http://mydomain.cloudapp.net', will browsers understand that this certificate is valid for the (...)cloudapp address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure uses the cloudapp.net domain by default but it's not Azure who would be responsible for resolving your custom domain to the your-app.cloudapp.net domain. Your SSL cert would not be valid for the cloudapp.net domain.

Instead what you need to do is configure the cloud service to use your custom domain as well as provide an A or CNAME record that maps your custom domain to the cloud service IP or your-app.cloudapp.net domain respectively. You would create the A or CNAME record with whoever you purchased your custom domain from.

You can read more about configuring custom domains with cloud services [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/).

Comment: And here is a link about configuring an SSL cert for a cloud service: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

Comment: Ok, so the trick is to point my custom domain to the '.cloudapp.net' address with the registrar, and then the certificate will be valid to my service host in azure. Thanks!